How to programmatically navigate pages in react-Native v=0.74?
I am new to react native and I have issue for routing pages in react native
solution for routing pages in react native
in login page if user is new so, user clicked on signup button that redirect user to sign up page but I don't know how to add routes in react native new version (version =0.74)

there are many react native navigations libraries
I assume you are using react-navigation if that's the case for an auth flow you will need many navigators with stacks, and theses stacks contains screens.
you can find an complete example here
https://github.com/flexbox/react-native-bootcamp/blob/main/hackathon/spacecraft/src/navigation/Navigator.tsx
basically it's
NavigationContainer
  Stack.Navigator
    Stack.Screen
      BottomTab
    Stack.Screen  
      Stack.Navigator
        Stack.Screen Login
        Stack.Screen Password


